# Editable annotations on terminal like sticky notes

Tags: command-line, gnu-screen

I use screen, which lets me use many terminals. However, because there are so many terminals sometimes I forget what I am doing. Is there any terminal application that can draw over a section of the terminal/take up some space, and show an editable notes section?

I don't want to run screen in screen :-p

Comment: Use `byobu`, a wrapper for `screen` and `tmux`. It can use custom scripts to set the status, so while the status is not directly editable, you could use simple shell scripts to get close.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe not what you're looking for exactly, but I have a script to add a string to the beginning of the bash prompt. It's called `shellname.sh` and looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash -x

if [[ -z "$ORIG_PS1" ]] ; then
  export ORIG_PS1="$PS1" ;
fi

export PS1="($1) $ORIG_PS1"
```

Then I can call `source ~/testname.sh "Shell Name Here"`. Note that you have to use `source` instead of running it directly so it can effect the local environment. For example:

```
stokastic@home:~/test# 
stokastic@home:~/test# source ~/shellname.sh "build shell"
(build shell) stokastic@home:~/test# 
(build shell) stokastic@home:~/test# echo "now my shell name is on the left"
now my shell name is on the left
(build shell) stokastic@home:~/test# make
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to set a custom title by adding this function to your .bashrc:

```
term_title() {
    unset PROMPT_COMMAND
    echo -ne "\033]0;${@}\007"
}
```

To set the terminal's title run this command in a new terminal:

```
term_title "New Terminal Name"
```

[image: Link to the image]

Answer (score 1):

One solution I use now is to just add a bash comment

`bash>  # this tab is for doing xyz.`

If you prefix the comment hash with a space ie. ' #', it won't even save it into your command line history.